# DTO in spring mvc

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, dto

I'm using spring mvc.
I have created the controller, view, pojo, dao.
Now I have the need to create an object composted from multiple objects pojo, is the case of creating a DTO?

Comment: what is this object intended for?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to build a composite kind of Object for view purposes only, then there is a good argument for a DTO.  If the composite is just an aggregation of the POJOs you can use org.springframework.ui.Model and just add attributes inside your Controller.  If there is logic and business rules that need to be applied, it is probably best to do this in a Service layer that sits between your Controller and your DAO.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you need to access properties of few POJOs on the client side and you want to reduce amount of calls from
client to server then yes. It is better to create a DTO object where place only necessary properties from POJOs that you will 
use on client side. And return this DTO as a result of a single call from client to server.